# script copy properties in AD( Powershell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I creating a script that copies  another users permissions and pastes them to the user but i get error message

```
   # import the Active Directory module in order to be able to use get-ADuser and Add-AdGroupMembe cmdlet
import-Module ActiveDirectory

# enter login name of the first user
$copy = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter login name of the second user
$paste  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: "

# copy-paste process. Get-ADuser membership     | then selecting membership                       | and add it to the second user
get-ADuser -identity $copy -properties memberof | select-object memberof -expandproperty memberof | Add-AdGroupMember -Members $paste
```

the error message

```
Add-AdGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
At line:11 char:101
+ ... memberof -expandproperty memberof | Add-AdGroupMember -Members $paste
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=CPT Helsinki...ba,DC=gov,DC=il:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
```

Comment: your error is self explanatory, are you using an elevated powershell session for executing this script?

Comment: Oops, now i'm running as an administrator but i get the error message
get-ADuser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'pubmeme10' under: 'DC=sheba,DC=gov,DC=il'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-ADuser -identity $copy -properties memberof | select-object membe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pubmeme10:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,M
   icrosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: Are you sure that user with that samaccountname exist???

Comment: The main issue with scripts like this is that you need a rather obvious naming convention to actually be able to use it without much thought since you're hitting SamAccountName.

Comment: yes, i am sure i usesamaccountname

Comment: how do i make it go a certain object

Comment: The error you put in the comment shows that `pubmeme10` is not a valid SamAccountName. For test, open ADUC, select a user, go Properties and find the _real_ SamAccountName for that user. The `-Identity` property is very precise.

Comment: I checked again the username is PUBMEME10. In my AD search I logged into the account where in UserLogon name is listed pubmeme10

Comment: Well... the error is very clear on this. Maybe try `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*pubmeme10*'"` and see if that gets you something.